# Efficient random function when I want only 0 or 1

Tags: c, performance, random

I know you can use `rand() % 2 to` get a random choice of 0 and 1 in C, but is there something more efficient?

My question is not so much about C specifically but about how random number generators work. If I understand correctly, they do some complicated math on the seed to get an even distribution between 0 and RAND_MAX, but is there a way to do less math if you just need a binary choice?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not, not if you need only one. If you need more, you can get one random number, and then you have 32 random binary numbers, one per bit.

Comment: Explain a bit what's the problem here. The latency to get one value or the time to get many values. Common PRNGs are all generating 32, 64 or 128 bits internally.

Comment: @AntonH That answers my question

Comment: @AntonH [Good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741842/efficient-random-function-when-i-want-only-0-or-1#comment78441167_45741842), but likely 31 bits with `int rand()` --> `[0...RAND_MAX]`

Comment: Note, if signed `int` divide/`%` is more expensive than `&`, consider `rand() % 2u` or `rand() & 1`.  `some_function_returning_int() % 2` --> 0,1 ,-1], so unless the compiler "knows" `rand()` returns only non-negative, emitted code is obliged to do a signed division/remainder.

Comment: Note that `RAND_MAX` is not always the full width of `unsigned int`. In MSVC `rand()` returns a value with 15 significant bits.

Comment: @chux Well spotted. I just had in mind the integer, forgot that `rand()` only gives a positive integer, so that the topmost bit (for sign) would always be 0.

Comment: @AntonH I too forgot that `rand()` returns `int` in my comment.

Comment: The low order bits on a `rand()` function needn't be very random.  You might do better using `rand() >= RAND_MAX / 2 ? 1 : 0` or thereabouts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler On ["or thereabouts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741842/efficient-random-function-when-i-want-only-0-or-1#comment78443665_45741842) I see an off by 1 --> `rand() > RAND_MAX / 2 ? 1 : 0;`  `>=` --> `>`.

Comment: @chux: the 'or thereabouts' was in there to allow for the possibility of being off-by-one — I'd not needed to do the calculation before this question, and I wasn't careful enough.

Comment: `(rand()/(RAND_MAX/2))` is likely to be optimised to something reasonably efficient.

Comment: These half interval calculations are assuming `RAND_MAX` is odd so the range [0,`RAND_MAX`] is even. I've never seen a implementation where it wasn't BTW and given `RAND_MAX>=32767` any bias would be small.

Comment: @rici Unclear on the goal of `(rand()/(RAND_MAX/2))` which would generate results of 0,1,2.  Were you thinking of `(rand()/(RAND_MAX/2  + 1u))`?

Comment: @chux: yep. That was the idea.

Comment: @persixty: if RAND_MAX is even, using the low (or any other) bit will also  be biased.

Comment: @rici True. I'm certainly not advocating just picking the low bit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "The low order bits on a rand() function needn't be very random" Are you saying that rand() % 2 is not as good?

Comment: @Ethan: it depends on the random number generator in `rand()`.  Be cautious if the program is doing something important — it probably doesn't matter if the program isn't important.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What makes a random number generator not good? There is some pattern? The sequence repeats? The numbers are not distributed evenly? All of the above and more?

Comment: Knuth spends a significant chunk of The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Semi-Numerical Methods, chapter 3  Random Numbers, discussing the issue.  That information doesn't fit into a comment.  Yes, patterns, repeats (short cycles), non-uniform distribution, and others (correlations, etc).  And there are tests.  At least 30 pages of material.  Try looking up Mersenne Twister and PRNG (pseudo-random number generation) too.  Wikipedia probably has useful information — it may be more approachable (and more easily obtained) than Knuth.

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to do less math if you just need a binary choice?

Yes, but it depends on how "good" a random distribution and sequence (or apparent lack)  is required.  C does not specify the quality of `rand()`.  With quality of randomness specified, alternative solutions exist.  How fast? - it depends on many things not supplied by OP.  If code is to use `rand()`, the below will modestly improve performance over a simple `rand() % 2u`

---

Call `rand()` once in a while to extract `n` random bits and use 1 of those bits per call.

This function uses `RAND_MAX` to rate the number of bits `n` received per `rand()` call.  A value of `RAND_MAX == 32767` or 0x7FFF would imply 15 random bits.

```
int rand01(void) {
  // Insure RAND_MAX is a power-of-2 - 1
  assert(((RAND_MAX + 1u) & RAND_MAX) == 0);

  static unsigned rmax = 0;
  static int rbits;
  if (rmax == 0) {
    rmax = RAND_MAX;
    rbits = rand();
  }
  rmax /= 2u;
  int r = rbits%2u;
  rbits /= 2u;
  return r;
}
```

Note that this approach does not reset the random state completely with `srand()` .   A `srand()` call is not aware of this function's state.

Comment: Aside: is not not reentrant or thread-safe but `rand()` is not either.

Comment: Was a bit a of a not not comment chux.

Comment: C uses a linear congruential generator which has a relatively short cycle (in comparison to better random number generators) and lacks the cryptographic unpredictability feature.  Always nice to use unsigned values and bit operators shift and AND when you're doing this type work.  Knuth's Semi-Numerical Algorithms is a great introduction to randomness (old, but always a classic).

Comment: @TheGreatContini Agree with the general idea.  Some deatils: The quality of `rand()` is often weak, yet an implementation could use better generators.  `rand()` using a linear congruential generator is common, but not required.  `rand()` cannot use cryptographic unpredictability as `rand()` is specified to be pseudo-random and "sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated" per a given seed.  An addition to C of  quality random generators, etc., is long overdue.

Comment: Can you explain your answer more? What does the code do?

Comment: @ehen Rather than explain each line of code - which parts need additional detail?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try using my method:

```
int i;
i = time(NULL) % 2;
```

this only works if you don't do more than one random per second but you can also do:

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
unsigned long random_number = (1000000 * tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec) % 2;
```

this will update your random number at a microsec rate.

Comment: `time(NULL)` returns `time_t` which is commonly an integer.  `time_t` is a _real type_ and so could be a `double`, in which case `time(NULL) % 2` will fail to compile.

Comment: `unsigned long random_number = (1000000 * tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec) % 2;` can be simplified to `unsigned long random_number = tv.tv_usec % 2;` with has less `int` OF/UB concerns too.